Given $(a+b)^2 + (c+d)^2 = 2023(a+b)(c+d)$ , what is the minimum value of $(\frac{a}{b+c+d} + \frac{b}{a+c+d})(\frac{c}{a+b+d} + \frac{d}{a+b+c})$

Given $(a+b)^2 + (c+d)^2 = 2023(a+b)(c+d)$ , what is the minimum value of $(\frac{a}{b+c+d} + \frac{b}{a+c+d})(\frac{c}{a+b+d} + \frac{d}{a+b+c})$ , where $a,b,c$ and $d \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$

My Try :
Arranges and divides both sides of the given equation by $(a+b+c+d)^2$
$(a+b + c+d)^2 = 2025(a+b)(c+d)$
$\dfrac{1}{2025} = \left(\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{b+c+d}{a} + 1}+\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{a+c+d}{b} + 1}\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{a+b+d}{c} + 1}+\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{a+b+c}{d} + 1}\right)$
given , $\frac{a}{ b+c+d}=w, \frac{b}{ a+c+d}=x, \frac{c}{ a+b+d}=y,\frac{d}{ a+b+c}=z$
$\dfrac{1}{2025}=\left(\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1}{w}+1}+\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1}{x}+1}\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1}{y}+1}+\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1}{z}+1}\right)$
From AM-HM inequality ,  use the fact that $\dfrac{a+1}{2} \geq \dfrac{2}{\frac{1}{a}+1}$
it becomes to  $\dfrac{w+x+2}{2} \geq 2 \left(\dfrac{1}{ \dfrac{1}{w}+1} + \dfrac{1}{ \dfrac{1}{x}+1} \right)$ and $\dfrac{y+z+2}{2} \geq 2 \left(\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1}{y}+1} + \dfrac{1}{ \dfrac{1}{z}+1} \right)$
finally , it ends up with $(w+x+2)(y+z+2) \geq \frac{16}{2025}$
which is not $(w+x)(y+z)$ as desire , I have try many times but not close to that form.

By Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality and $2ab \le (a + b)^2/2$, we have
\begin{align*}
 \frac{a}{b+c+d} + \frac{b}{a+c+d}
 &\ge \frac{(a + b)^2}{a(b + c + d) + b(a + c + d)}\\
 &= \frac{(a + b)^2}{2ab + (a + b)(c + d)}\\
 &\ge \frac{(a + b)^2}{(a + b)^2/2 + (a + b)(c + d)}\\
 &= \frac{2(a + b)}{(a + b) + 2(c + d)}.
\end{align*}
Similarly, we have
$$\frac{c}{a+b+d} + \frac{d}{a+b+c}
\ge \frac{2(c + d)}{2(a + b) + (c + d)}.$$
Letting $x = a + b, y = c + d$, using $x^2 + y^2 = 2023xy$, we have
\begin{align*}
 f
 &\ge \frac{2(a + b)}{(a + b) + 2(c + d)}\cdot \frac{2(c + d)}{2(a + b) + (c + d)}\\
 &= \frac{4xy}{2x^2 + 2y^2 + 5xy}\\
 &= \frac{4}{4051}.
\end{align*}
Also, when $a = b, c = d$ and $(a+b)^2 + (c+d)^2 = 2023(a+b)(c+d)$, we have
$f = \frac{4}{4051}$.
Thus, the minimum is $\frac{4}{4051}$.
